# Handlebars use the @ in templates

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

When trying to do something like this in my template :

```
{{#if @attributes}}
    <p>{{@attributes.section}}</p>  
{{/if}}
```

Nothing appears in the generated HTML. I have the @ sign in my JSON file so I wanted to know if the @ is a reserved character in Handlebars or if I'm missing something.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you would need to nest your json data in order to get this to display correctly. On Handlebars github issues they talk about this specifically. what you want is a structure like

data = {"data": { "someValue": "@attribute" }}

then you can access it like so

```
<p>{{[data].someValue}}</p>
```

for reference [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/110) is the github bug discussion.